# ListView without items on first pass

Tags: asp.net, linq

I'm building an ASP.NET application. I'm using a ListView to show some Entities however my listview doesn't have items on the first pass. I mean, they show up on the page, but this code only works when I refresh the page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    fillFeatures();
}

private void fillFeatures()
{
    using (Entities myEntities = new Entities())
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("Filling features.. \n");
        foreach (ListViewItem item in ListView1.Items)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("FOR \n");
            CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox)item.FindControl("Checkbox");
            TextBox description = (TextBox)item.FindControl("descriptionTextbox");

            //Try to get an existing relation
            int featureId = Int32.Parse(((Label)item.FindControl("idLabel")).Text);

            PlaceHasFeature phf = (from p in myEntities.PlaceHasFeature
                                   where p.place_id == placeId && p.feature_id == featureId
                                   select p).SingleOrDefault();

            if (phf != null)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("Checking " + phf.Feature.name + "\n");
                //Relation exists
                checkbox.Checked = true;
                description.Text = phf.description;
            }
            else
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("Didn't find relation for " + featureId + "\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Console output:

When I open the link: Filling features...

After refresh: Filling features... FOR FOR FOR (...)

Anyone knows the cause of this?

Comment: It seems the ListView1.Items are populated after the Page_Load event.  Is this all of the code?  Typically you would only want to call fillFeatures only once.  Is this what you would want as well?  Wrap the fillFeatures call in Page_Load to look like if(!PostBack) { fillFeatures(); }.

Comment: The ListView1.Items are populated by a EntityDataSource without my intervention. If I put if(!isPostBack) it never fills the checkboxes.

Comment: Yes this is all the code that happens on Page_Load. The rest is just an event on the SubmitButton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the issue is due to the [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx), where the page load event occurs before the individual controls load event:

> The Page object calls the OnLoad method on the Page object, and then
>   recursively does the same for each child control until the page and
>   all controls are loaded. The Load event of individual controls occurs
>   after the Load event of the page.

I believe you have a couple of options. Move the `fillFeatures` method to the [Page.LoadComplete Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.loadcomplete.aspx):

> The LoadComplete event occurs after all postback data and view-state
>   data is loaded into the page and after the OnLoad method has been
>   called for all controls on the page.

Or move the `fillFeatures` method to the ListBox's [DataBound Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basedataboundcontrol.databound.aspx). Though I would suspect that the Page.LoadComplete Event is really the better of the two options.

Comment: I have an asp:Button and if I click it with the postbackURL '<%# "ManagePlace.aspx?Id=" + Eval("id") %>' it works fine and loads the checkboxes correctly, but on entering the link and pressing enter it doesn't.

Comment: I'm not sure where to go from here. asp.net is not my forte; from the description, it sounded like a page-life-cycle issue. Since the foreach still isn't being called in the `LoadComplete` event, then there's something else going on. It could just be that the `Entities` are not being populated correctly the first time the page is loaded?

Comment: Well I managed to do it by using the ItemDataBound event. Thanks.